# Faster way of retrieving page Meta tags in Chrome Extension default pop-up?

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-chrome-extension

I am fiddling with this extension which retrieves the title, url, and meta tags from the current tab when the icon is clicked. The data is displayed in the default pop-up, however, the meta data is delayed (by a second or two) due to the use of AJAX. Is there a way to get this information as quickly as using tabs.url and tabs.title for the url and title?

Here is the code from the js file:

```
chrome.tabs.getSelected(null,function(tab) { // null defaults to current window
    var title = tab.title;
    var url = tab.url;

    document.getElementById("title").innerHTML = title;
    document.getElementById("url").innerHTML = url;


    var txt = "";
    // sample url used here, you can make it more dynamic as per your need.
    // used AJAX here to just hit the url & get the page source from those website. It's used here like the way CURL or file_get_contents (https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) from PHP used to get the page source.
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        error: function() {
            txt = "Unable to retrieve webpage source HTML";
        }, 
        success: function(response){
            // will get the output here in string format
            // used $.parseHTML to get DOM elements from the retrieved HTML string. Reference: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsehtml/
            response = $.parseHTML(response);
            $.each(response, function(i, el){
                if(el.nodeName.toString().toLowerCase() == 'meta' && $(el).attr("name") != null && typeof $(el).attr("name") != "undefined"){
                    txt += $(el).attr("name") +"="+ ($(el).attr("content")?$(el).attr("content"):($(el).attr("value")?$(el).attr("value"):"")) +"<br>";
                    console.log($(el).attr("name") ,"=", ($(el).attr("content")?$(el).attr("content"):($(el).attr("value")?$(el).attr("value"):"")), el);
                }
            });
        },
        complete: function(){
            document.getElementById("desc").innerHTML = txt;
        }
    });
      
  });
```

This is not a duplicate question. The suggested article that was linked to my question is in regards to inject a div onto the active window. I am trying to retrieve data from it and use it in the default-popup.

Comment: I'd not use ``innerHTML` when you are testing to non-HTML text and instead use `.textContent` as `innerHTML` invokes the HTML parser.

Comment: whether I used textContent or innerHTML, the meta fields show up later than the url and title. The url and title are almost instantaneous.

Comment: That's because you are getting them straight from the currently loaded page. It seems like the AJAX is there so that  you can get info. from another page. Is that the case?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. I could not find a solution to get the meta fields without AJAX, and that's what brought me here. Seeing if there is any native chrome method that will achieve that...

Comment: You can access the dom of the tab in a content script, and send json data back to your extension script by passing a message: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/messaging/

Answer (score -1):

Just query the DOM using standard DOM API's and the JavaScript `switch` to handle the different possible attributes you're interested in.

```js
// Gather all the <meta> elements into a node list and loop over them
document.querySelectorAll("meta").forEach(function(meta){
  // Test for specific values for the name attribute and act accordingly
  switch(meta.name.toLowerCase()){
    case "description":
      console.log("Description: " + meta.content);
      break;
    case "title":
      console.log("Title: " + meta.content);
      break;      
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="description" content="specifically descrpitive content about your page here">
  <meta name="title" content="some page title">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=yourfonthere" rel="stylesheet">
  <title>Page Title Here</title>
</head>
<body>
  <!-- begin page content -->
  <div id="pagewrap">
    <h1 class="header"> Welcome to HTML + CSS!</h1>
    <div id="flexwrapper">

      <div class="box1">
        <p>Box 01 content goes here! </p>
      </div>

      <div class="box2">
        <p>Box 02 content goes here! </p>
      </div>

      <div class="box3">
        <p>Box 03 content goes here! </p>
      </div>

    </div>
    <!--END FLEXWRAP-->
    <footer><span>Awwwwwww yeah<span></footer>
  </div><!--END PAGEWRAP-->
  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I have tried this out. It is fast, however, the issue with this is that it is retrieving the meta description of the default-popup (in my case, "index.html") instead of the page that is in the active tab. Instead of "document.querySelectorAll" would there be another way to point it to the document inside the activeTab?